# distribution of two dependent Uniform to the power of Uniform

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

What is the pdf of $z = u_1^{b-1}u_2^{b}$, 
where $u_1, u_2, b \sim Uniform(0,1)$ and they are all independent.

Referring to [distribution of Uniform to the power of Uniform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968194/distribution-of-uniform-to-the-power-of-uniform/1968985#1968985) , I can get the pdf of $u = (u_1u_2)^b$, $pdf(u) = 1$, i.e. $u\sim Uniform(0,1)$.

But in $z = u_1^{b-1}u_2^{b} = \dfrac{(u_1u_2)^b}{u_1}$, the numerator and denominator are dependent, and it is hard to get the joint pdf.

Thanks very much!